# Alternative to enable and disable trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

What is the alternative to enabling and disabling trigger for this example?
This is my trigger and I have a scenario where it should not be allowed to do update directly column Column33 in Table33 (by executing query UPDATE Table33 SET Column33='123'), but it should be allowed to do update of that column from other triggers that are doing some calculations. It works when I disable trigger Triger33 in other triggers, do the update inside triggers and then enable this trigger again. This solution is not good. Is there a way that I can put some kind of a condition to this trigger so that it allows updates that are not direct so that I can avoid disabling and enabling in other triggers?

```
create trigger [dbo].[Trigger33]
on [dbo].[Table33]
AFTER UPDATE
as
    if UPDATE(Column33)
    begin
        raiserror('It is not allowed to update Column33 in Table33', 16,1)
        rollback
    end
```

Comment: Would adding "AND @@TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL = 1" do the trick?

Comment: You might also need to check to see if the value actually changed: "AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED I JOIN DELETED D ON D.ID = I.ID WHERE I.Column33 <> D.Column33)". The comparison may need to be a bit more complicated if null values or case-sensitivity needs to be considered.

Comment: Set `CONTEXT_INFO` in the other trigger and check it in this trigger.

Comment: Or use the more modern [`session_context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to allow the triggers to chat with one another.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow trigger code to globally bypass other triggers with the [nested triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-nested-triggers-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15) server configuration option, or the [NESTED_TRIGGERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=sql-server-ver15#nested_triggers) database configuration option (for partially contained databases).

eg

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'nested triggers', 0 ;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
create table t(id int primary key)
create table t2(id int primary key)

go
create trigger te_nope on t2 after insert 
as
begin
  throw 50001, 'nope', 1;
end

go

create trigger t_ins on t after insert
as
begin
  insert into t2(id) select id from inserted 
end

go

insert into t2(id) values (1)  --fails
--Msg 50001, Level 16, State 1, Procedure te_nope, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 32]
--nope

insert into t(id) values (1) --suceeds
--(1 row affected)
--
--(1 row affected)
```

Other options include shoving a secret into CONTEXT_INFO that's checked in the inner trigger, or performing an impersonation that is checked to modify the behavior of nested triggers.